# how to configure string indexer for object which has a child object?

Tags: typescript

I've defined a string indexer like this:

```
interface StringIndexed {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
}
```

And then I've applied this string indexer to another interface like this:

```
export interface Facility extends StringIndexed {
    "@ID": string;
    "@Name": string;
    AdditionalFacilityInfo: AdditionalFacilityInfo
}
```

This works well and as expected for the first 2 properties but fails for the third property.  What kind of approach can I use so that I can still access all other properties with a string indexer but the third property with the object type won't fail b/c of not being string indexable?  Is there some sort of declarative tag that I can put on the third property?  Is there any proper way to configure that?  I'm also open to workarounds/hacks

Comment: How about using `[key: string | AdditonalFacilityInfo]` inside `StringIndexed` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with string indexers(a quick google shows it's an ML thing), but I think `[key:string]: string | object | undefined` should work. Or if you want it to be `AdditionalFacilityInfo`, then `[key: string | AdditonalFacilityInfo | undefined]` will work too.

Comment: please share reproducabel example. `AdditionalFacilityInfo`